# Checking contents of string C++

Tags: c++, string

If I had a program reading a file that contained something along the lines of "Boss1 Dave Jim Boss3 Coleen Boss 7 Harris Todd Elaine" and I'm trying to separate the inputs into a list of bosses and a list of names, I would check each string inputted, but how can I tell if the person is a boss or not? I would set up something like this to begin with:

```
void read(std::istream& is, Bosses<std::string>& bossList, Employees<std::string> empList){

    std::string name;
    while(!is.eof()){
        is >> name;
        }
    }
```

But I would need to check in the while loop if something like `name=="Boss_"` but I don't understand strings well enough to know how to set this up.

Comment: Start with understanding strings well enough, then move on to more complicated tasks.

Comment: and use `while( is >> name ){ ... }`, it will also check for other errors besides just `EOF`

Comment: If you are guaranteed that a boss will start with `Boss`, then you can do `std::string::find( "Boss" )`. If that returns `0` (start of string), then that is a boss.

Comment: It is guaranteed, @ssel, I now have : `if(name.find("Boss")==0)` then it is a boss and goes to the correct list. Testing it now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the insertion operator to parse the string of names as **your string is whitespace delimited, and the insertion operator skips over whitespace (by default)**:

```
void read(std::istream& is, Bosses<std::string>& bossList, Employees<std::string> empList) {
    std::string temp;
    std::vector<std::string> all_names;
    //the insertion operator reads the string and bypasses all whitespace by default
    while (is >> temp) {

        //find bosses by using `std::string
        if (temp.find("Boss") != std::string::npos) {
            boosList.push_back(temp);//you didn't state what container `Bosses` uses but, `push_back is valid for `lists`, `vectors` and `deques`
        }
        else {
            empList.push_back(temp);//you didn't state what container `Employees` uses but, `push_back is valid for `lists`, `vectors` and `deques`
        }
    }
}
```